# Setting Outlook.com contacts and calendar on OSX

Tags: macos, contacts, calendar

There are similar questions regarding the synchronization of Outlook.com on AskDifferent, mostly related to the native OSX Mail app. However, I'm particularly interested in connecting the **Contacts and Calendar apps on OSX** to my Outlook.com account.

Is there a way to use my Outlook.com account to integrate with the contacts and calendar apps?

I am aware that Outlook.com does not implement the native Exchange protocol, however considering adding an Outlook.com account on iOS seems to work just fine for mail, contacts and calendar entries, there is perhaps a decent way to achieve the same on OSX?

Comment: Huh, When I go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars on my iPhone there is an "outlook.com" option, but not when I go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts on my Mac. Does outlook.com have CalDAV or CardDAV anywhere in its options?

Answer (score 14):

For desktop usage, Outlook.com uses IMAP for mail.  However, it doesn't provide CardDAV or CalDAV access for contacts and calendars.  For mobile usage, Outlook.com uses Exchange Active Sync.  I'm not aware of any Mac desktop apps that support Exchange Active Sync.

You should tell Microsoft that this is important to you.  When you login to Outlook.com, click the settings icon and then click on Feedback.  Tell them what you want, why it matters, and what you will do in lieu of having this available to you.  For example, I said this in my feedback to them about this topic (feel free to borrow this, although I'd recommend changing it to whatever is important to you):

> I want to be able to sync my calendar and contacts across all devices
>   that I use.  I can get my calendar and contacts on my phone, but not
>   on my Mac.  Please make it possible for me to see my calendar and
>   contacts on Mac desktop clients.  Gmail can sync my calendar and
>   contacts to my Mac desktop applications, which makes it very difficult
>   for me to use Outlook.com instead of Gmail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree that notifying Microsoft on this is a first step. However, despite your good advise, the problem cannot be solved with this for now.

Comment: I feel like using Feedback is pointless. They ignored requests for IMAP for about 10 years, and that is a much bigger feature than CalDAV/CardDAV. As a workaround, I’m keeping my contacts and calendars in iCloud. But I would like to do it all on Outlook.com.

Comment: Apple doesn't support ActiveSync on Mac and Microsoft doesn't support CalDAV/CardDAV ... Outlook.com users suffer ...

Comment: Any updates on this? This is giving me grief.

Comment: There are no changes in Outlook 2016 to improve this.

Comment: it's 2016 and this still didn't happen... cardDAV support come on MS!

Comment: Can you explain how this is solely on Microsoft's end? If iOS can do it, it's just 0s and 1s... you could make a "mobile API" client for macOS as well, correct?

Comment: There are two different but related concerns here. First, the desktop APIs are optimized for desktop usage, and the mobile APIs are optimized for mobile usage.  There are differences in how information is presented, when it is presented, how much is presented, and more.  Using mobile APIs on a desktop client might not produce a usable application.  Second, there are licensing requirements for using Exchange ActiveSync, and it's up to people who are lawyers to say whether it would be possible to legally develop an EAS client for a desktop platform. IANAL, thankfully. :)

Comment: In fact, now it's possible to set up Outlook.com (even if on custom domain) with Exchange on OSX. You should use your normal email address as username, a generated app password if you have 2FA (or a normal one) as a password and https://m.hotmail.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx as internal & external URL when prompted. Then, OSX will happily offer to synchronize mail, calendars, reminders etc. with your Outlook.com account.

Answer (score 7):

I have one suggestion for Calendars which I use. You can go to http://calendar.live.com, and get a sharing link for a calendar. Take the ICS link, open Calendar on your Mac. Then, go to Import Subscribed Calendar and paste this link. Make sure to replace webcals:// with https://. This gives you a read-only subscription and at present, is the only workaround to Microsoft's stubbornness. I have no solution for Contacts though.

Comment: calendars which I subscribed to on outlook.com aren't visible though so you got to subscribe to them seperately from the calendars app. Best workaround yet though.

Comment: That's correct.